# Hosting a tomcat web application in a subdirectory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am trying to do a feasibility check on the below problem.

I have a tomcat running on EC2 machines which is load balanced using ELB. Currently the ELB is accessible using https://abc.example.com (using ROUTE53 hosted zone).

I want to achieve something where I can reach the application from https://example.com/abc

Is this even possible ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot point DNS to a path on your site.

DNS converts `abc.example.com` into the IP address of the ELB/server. The request for `/abc` is then sent to the ELB/server on the designated port.

You should consult your web server docs to perform path based routing or consider using an ALB (Application Load Balancer) to perform [path based routing](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-achieve-path-based-routing-alb/).